# Using CLI command in shell script

Tags: shell, command-line

I have this code in, which is executable in normal CLI, but how can I apply this to a file?

```
sort <filename> | uniq | cut -f 1 -d "," | uniq -c |sed -e "s/^[ \t]*//"
```

It always tells me something like command not found.

Edit:
My command works in CLI, but I want to apply it in a bash script. Now my question is how I can apply this command in the script, to however filename $1 and then save the output in another variable, which can be read like a file line by line or similar.

So I tried with this piece of bash code and "./script.sh filename.txt"

```
#!/bin/bash

lines=sort $1 | uniq | cut -f 1 -d "," | uniq -c |sed -e 's/^[ \t]*//'
```

And it shows me this error when executing:

```
./filename.txt: line 1: YKL112W,YKL112W: command not found
```

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far by editing your question.

Comment: I believe there is something like missed in the way you apply :)
Could you show your attempts along with the output you get - this will significantly increase the chances of getting something like help :)

Comment: It would be helpful to see what "something like" is, i.e. the full error message. It's further unclear what you mean by "apply". Do you want to write a script that takes the pathname of a file on the command line? As others have already commented, please update your question with the details regarding the error and what code _exactly_ produced the error.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you have a syntax error in your script. The line

```bsh
lines=sort $1 | uniq | cut -f 1 -d "," | uniq -c |sed -e 's/^[ \t]*//'
```

means:

- assign the string `sort` to a variable `lines`
- then, execute the command stored in the variable `$1` while piping the output to `uniq`, `cut`, `uniq` and `sed`, respectively.

Since `$1` - the argument you gave to your script - contains a filename, the shell would try to execute that file (as if it were a script, e.g.) even though it is only a text file; hence the error message.

If you want to assign the result of the command to the variable `line`, you need to perform a "command substitution", as in

```
lines="$(sort "$1" | uniq | cut -f 1 -d "," | uniq -c |sed -e 's/^[ \t]*//')"
```

I would also recommend using [shellcheck](https://shellcheck.net) to identify problems with shell scripts.